# Image not filtering from recyclerview list

Tags: android, filter, android-recyclerview

I am implementing code for filter the data from recyclerview with name, its working fine. But when i enter name the whole data related to that name showing but image is not changing the same image is stable on their place not changing with the data, how i can do this thing plz comment.

My Fragment:-

```
userName.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            String editValue = String.valueOf(s);
            filter(editValue);
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });

private void filter(String text){
    List<MessageAdvanceModel.MessageAdvDetail> temp = new ArrayList();
    for(MessageAdvanceModel.MessageAdvDetail d: list){
        if(d.getName().toLowerCase().contains(text.toLowerCase())){
            temp.add(d);
        }
    }
    messageAdvAdapter.updateList(temp);
}
```

Adapter:-

```
holder.userName.setText(arrayList.get(position).getName());
 String image = arrayList.get(position).getImage();
 byte[] decodedString = android.util.Base64.decode(image, Base64.DEFAULT);
            Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
            holder.userImage.setImageBitmap(decodedByte);



 public void updateList(List<MessageAdvanceModel.MessageAdvDetail> list){
    arrayList = list;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: can you please share the code snippet of onBind method of adapter class

Comment: @NitinJain plz check, i added

Comment: Do not use `BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray` on main thread . Also Use `Filterable` for filtering data .

Answer (score 0):

try this hack

```
holder.userImage.setImageBitmap(null);
holder.userImage.postDelayed(()->holder.userImage.setImageBitmap(decodedByte),200);
```

Comment: not working, it takes 200 to set image but again set previous(Same) image.

Comment: ok can you please upload a video it will help to understand more?